# Using 'and' expressions in 'while' loops in Python

Tags: python, list, while-loop, int, expression

within my program I have a list, and I would like a loop until all of a column of the list equals 2. All of the items in the column are numbers but some are formatted as strings and some are formatted as integers, because they are changed in other parts of the program.
Below are 3 solutions I have tried, I am running python 2.7.

```
while (int(newlist[0][1]) != 2) and (int(newlist[1][1]) != 2) etc... != 2:
```

The problem I am having is that the loop is ending when only one of the list items (rather than the whole column) equals 2

```
while int(newlist[0-8][1]) != 2:


while int(newlist[0 and 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and 5 and 6 and 7 and 8][1]) != 2:
```

If anybody could tell me what I'm doing wrong or a better way of doing it, I would really appreciate the help

Comment: In your first example, you want the `while` loop to continue if any of the items is not 2.  So, you want to use `or` instead of `and`.  Alternatively, you can write `while not (something == 2 and something_else == 2 and .... )`.

Comment: @LukeWoodward: I had been about to write that! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expressions in brackets are evaluated to a single value: `newlist[0-8]` is the same as `newlist[-8]`, and `newlist[0 and 1 and 2 and 3]` is the same as  `newlist[0]`. You want [`any`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
while any(int(newsublist[1]) != 2 for newsublist in newlist):
```

Comment: I think the asker may be after `any` instead.  If the `while` loop should terminate when all items are 2, it should keep going if any item is not 2.

Comment: that is what I was looking for, thank you phihag and Luke Woodward!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for loop. Lets say `L` is your list, now we can iterate over the rows, each of which is a list itself, like this:

```
column = 1
for row in L:
  while int(row[column]) != 2:
    do_this()
    increase_column()
```

Make sure the while loop terminates by increasing row[column] so it eventually fails the while test.